# R - stringdist aFind() method, no maxDist parameter

Tags: r, stringdist

The documentation for aFind, specifies a maxDist paramater you can use, but there is no maxDist parameter you can pass into aFind?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf

using this code:

```
result = afind(ae_target_term, ae_search_term,method="cosine", maxDist = 0.2)
```

just returns

> Error in afind(ae_target_term, ae_search_term, method = "cosine",
> maxDist = 0.2): unused argument (maxDist = 0.2) Traceback:

Answer (score 1):

`maxDist` is not argument of the function `afind` , it is argument of the functions `grab` , `grabl` and `extract` .

Comment: so I cant do an approcimate aFind with a tolerance, I have to wrap my own function around it to my tolerance?